# tracking a location using start and stop buttons using geolocation

Tags: jquery, html

ccepts his failure to shut a tunnel leading to football terraces "was the direct cause" of 96 deaths.

```
put returns between paragraphs

► for linebreak add 2 spaces at end

► _italic_ or **bold**

► indent code by 4 spaces

► backtick escapes `like _so_`

► quote by placing > at start of line

► to make links

<http://foo.com>
[foo](http://foo.com)
<a href="http://foo.com">foo</a>

► basic HTML also allowed
```

Comment: What exactly do u need? Im user on ur page, and when i click on 'Start' button - want do u want know or store or something?

Comment: i want to display a map and track journey using start and stop buttons

Comment: I click start, and u want store ALL my location ? Or only location on your site?

Comment: just the location on the site

Comment: Response.Cookies.Set()  Response.Cookies.Add()  and then send to server?